# Why Am I Getting This Stretching On My Texture?

Tags: texturing, uv

I have this piece of concrete that is stretching a lot on the sides:
[image]

I've tried applying scale/rotation, but that didn't help. Any ideas? Thanks!

Comment: Could you show your material node setup and the UV map overlayed upon the texture?

Comment: Did you apply scale *before* unwrapping?

Comment: @PGmath: I did not... this was after. That may be the issue. I'll give it a try and report back. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

It appears that the UV maps for the sides of your object (the top is fine) are not properly aligned with the texture and/or not properly scaled. I would need to see your UV map overplayed on the texture to give any more help, though.